# Error while making request: socket hang up. Error code: ECONNRESET

Tags: firebase, econnreset

I'm using node.js as a backend server for sending push notification from the Firebase Cloud Messaging service. The notifications are working fine with local server but on live server, I get this error:

> Error while making request: socket hang up. Error code: ECONNRESET

Things to consider are that...

- Number of users are in the thousands on live server
- Firebase version is `firebase-admin@6.5.1`
- Previously unregistered tokens are still there. But now registered tokens are being stored.

This is my code for sending notifications:

```js
for (let c = 0; c < tokens.length; c++) 
{
    let notifyTo = tokens[c];
    const platform = platforms[c];

    let payload;
    if (platform === "ios") {
        payload = {
            notification: {
                title: "title",
                subtitle :"messgae",
                sound: "default",
                badge: "1"
            },
            data: {
                sendFrom: "",
                notificationType: "",
                flag: "true"
            }
        };
    } else if (platform === "android") {
        payload = {
            data: {
                title: "",
                message : "",
                flag: "true"
            }
        };
    }

    const registrationtoken = notifyTo;

    await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationtoken, payload)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("Successfully sent message:");
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error sending message: ");
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is caused by your function taking too long to respond to the client (more than 60 seconds) and is caused by the following line:

```js
await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationtoken, payload)
```

Because you are waiting for each call of `sendToDevice()` individually, you are running your for-loop in synchronous sequential order, rather than asynchronously in parallel.

To avoid this, you want to make use of array mapping and `Promise.all()` which will allow you to build a queue of `sendToDevice()` requests. As in your current code, any failed messages will be silently ignored, but we will also count them.

Your current code makes use of two arrays, `tokens` and `platforms`, so in the code below I use a callback for [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) that takes two arguments - the current mapped value (from `tokens`) and it's index (your for-loop's `c` value). The index is then used to get the correct platform entry.

```js
let fcmPromisesArray = tokens.map((token, idx) => {
    let platform = platforms[idx];

    if (platform === "ios") {
        payload = {
            notification: {
                title: "title",
                subtitle :"messgae",
                sound: "default",
                badge: "1"
            },
            data: {
                sendFrom: "",
                notificationType: "",
                flag: "true"
            }
        };
    } else if (platform === "android") {
        payload = {
            data: {
                title: "",
                message : "",
                flag: "true"
            }
        };
    }

    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload) // note: 'await' was changed to 'return' here
        .then(function (response) {
          return true; // success
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error sending message to ", token);
            return false; // failed
        });
});

let results = await Promise.all(fcmPromisesArray); // wait here for all sendToDevice() requests to finish or fail
let successCount = results.reduce((acc, v) => v ? acc + 1 : acc, 0); // this minified line just counts the number of successful results

console.log(`Successfully sent messages to ${successCount}/${results.length} devices.`);
```

After this snippet has run, don't forget to send a result back to the client using `res.send(...)` or similar.