# Getting "Socket hang up" error when calling an API from Firebase functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, sockets, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a backend for my application using firebase functions. I want to make a call to an API from my backend. When I make the call from Postman to the API, the API works fine but the call takes 10-20 seconds. I am looking for a way to make the call from my firebase functions backend.

```
exports.generate = functions.https.onRequest( (req, res) => {
  corsHandler(req, res, () => {
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    const prompt = req.query.text;
    const apiKeySD =
     "key";
    const endpointSD = "https://stablediffusionapi.com/api/v3/text2img";

    const data = {
      "key": apiKeySD,
      "prompt": prompt,
      "negative_prompt": "",
      "width": "256",
      "height": "256",
      "samples": "1",
      "num_inference_steps": "20",
      "seed": null,
      "guidance_scale": 7.5,
      "webhook": null,
      "track_id": null,
    };
    const generationOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      timeout: 20000,
      headers: {
        "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(JSON.stringify(data)),
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
      body: data,
    };
    https.request(endpointSD, generationOptions, (sdRes:any) => {
      let dataSD = "";
      sdRes.on("data", (chunk:any) => {
        dataSD += chunk;
      });
      sdRes.on("end", () => {
        const response = JSON.parse(dataSD);
        const images = response.output;
        res.send(images);
      });
    }).on("error", (err:any) => {
      res.send("Error occured during generation" + err);
    });
  });
});
```

The log from firebase:

```
ERROR 2022-12-25T14:31:46.524426Z [resource.labels.functionName: generate] [labels.executionId: apbs87dr3l5f] Error: socket hang up at connResetException (node:internal/errors:705:14) at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:518:23) at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35) at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:552:15) at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1358:12) at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
  {
    "textPayload": "Error: socket hang up\n    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:705:14)\n    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:518:23)\n    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35)\n    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:552:15)\n    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1358:12)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)",
    "insertId": "63a85ed20008008affab5af6",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_function",
      "labels": {
        "project_id": "hufusion",
        "region": "us-central1",
        "function_name": "generate"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2022-12-25T14:31:46.524426Z",
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "labels": {
      "instance_id": "00c61b117cda64fea6286b0f26e0be07b4eadab5bb72817b9a3ee93932a7180c204fcbd8cf5aae7bd6140ec301a231eac74aa0311c81559c4b74eb",
      "execution_id": "apbs87dr3l5f"
    },
    "logName": "projects/hufusion/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
    "trace": "projects/hufusion/traces/e972f60ed325b739363d5972d1bd64c1",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2022-12-25T14:31:46.795046411Z"
  }
```

I tested the SD API using Postman, it works as expected, I also tested it using python. I checked the firebase logs but I did not find anything that helped.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons for socket hangup/reset in applications,at times the cloud function also will result in resetting the function if it did not return anything back and keeps on going for a long time.As far your code function seems to be not correctly returning the promise.
I would also suggest refactoring your code to return a proper value so that the [cloud functions return a promise](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript) that resolves only when all of the async work is complete in your function,something around as below:

`return getAllData().then(...).catch(...)`

It may also be worth checking your environment to see if you have any PROXY settings that might affect this. I would also suggest refactoring your code to return a proper value so
Also check out these similar examples:

- [What does socket hangup actually mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995184/nodejs-what-does-socket-hang-up-actually-mean)
- [Socket hang up error issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767005/why-am-i-getting-error-socket-hang-up-response)
- [How to handle socket hang up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62607651/how-to-handle-error-socket-hang-up-while-waiting-node-and-react)
- [Socket hangup error while making request api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59233278/error-while-making-request-socket-hang-up-error-code-econnreset)

Also check this helpful thread for details on [Rest API firebase cloud functions typescript firestore](https://blog.logrocket.com/rest-api-firebase-cloud-functions-typescript-firestore/)